# If $X\sim U\{1,2,3,\cdots n\}$, $Y|X=x\sim U\{1,2,3,\cdots,x\}$ find $P(Y=j)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

I think that

\begin{eqnarray}
P(Y=j)&=& \sum_{x=1}^nP(Y=j|X=x)P(X=x)\\
&=& \sum_{x=1}^n(\frac{1}{x})(\frac{1}{n})\\
&=& \frac{1}{n}\sum_{x=1}^n\frac{1}{x}
\end{eqnarray}

This is correct?

Comment: You are almost right! Just note that $P(Y=j|X=x)=0$ for $j>x$ and not $1/x$ and correct your sum :)

Answer (score 0):

**The answer below was written before the OP specified that $X$ and $Y$ were dependent. In light of that information, it's obviously incorrect so please disregard!**

Is $j$ related to $X$ in any way? Otherwise, the answer is just $P(Y=j) = \frac{1}{n}$ since $Y$ is uniform over $\{1,...,n\}$: $$
\begin{align}
P(Y=j) &= \sum_{x=1}^n P(Y=j, X=x) \\
&= \sum_{x=1}^n P(Y=j | X=x) P(X=x) \\
&= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{x=1}^n P(Y=j | X=x) \\
&= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{x=1}^n P(Y=j) ~~~~\text{ since $Y$ doesn't depend on $X$}\\
&= \frac{1}{n} \, \left( n \cdot P(Y=j) \right) ~\text{ again because $Y$ doesn't depend on $X$}\\
&= P(Y=j) \\
&= 1/n ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\text{ since $Y$ is uniform on $1 \ldots n$}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: The relation is that $Y|X $ is uniformly distributed in $\{0,1,2,\cdots, X\}.$

Comment: This condition will probably change the answer

Comment: I agree that this answer is not correct - Y is not independent of X, as the OP clearly states in the title

Comment: @Tom - originally it was not specified in the question whether X and Y were conditionally related. That's why I ask if they are related at the top of the post. Please don't ding me on this.

Comment: @ted Sorry did not know that